# Plotting matrices and defining a LineStyle for i.e. every 3rd line

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, linestyle

In my Code I use `plot(x,y)` where `x and y` are `16x12` matrices. Now I want to define style rules like for example 'the first two lines should be red, then two lines blue' or 'every 3rd line should be `LineStyle --`'.... I thought of defining a `LineStyle and a Color-Array` and ploting the matrices line by line with a `for-loop` or something like that, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I think you need to use `hold on` and call `plot` or `line` multiple times.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Not necessarily, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [`LineStyleOrder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) axis property. So setting every third line to be dashed can be done like this:

```
data = rand(9);
set(gca, 'LineStyleOrder','-|-|--'); %// note you can replace '-|-|--' with {'-','-','--'} if you prefer
hold on;
plot(data);
```

You can do the same for colour using the `ColorOrder` property so having the first 2 lines red and the next 2 blue (and then repeating) is

```
set(gca, 'ColorOrder',[1 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1;0 0 1]);
```

However if you mix the two, it will only repeat after every 12 lines:

```
set(gca,'ColorOrder',[1 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1;0 0 1],...
        'LineStyleOrder','-|-|--')
```

i.e. this will cycle through your specified `ColorOrder` *within* your `LineStyleOrder` (i.e. for each line style, it cycles through all the colours) so in this case the first two lines are solid red, the next tow are solid blue, the next two are solid red again, the next two are solid blue again then lines 9 and 10 will be dashed red and lines 11 and 12 will be dashed blue and then this pattern repeat.

So using them individually will work (just make sure you use this in conjunction with `hold on` even if you're plotting it all in one go) but if you want to cycle through colours independently of line styles then you will have to loop.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I knew there had to be something like that! Thanky you.